# Determining corners of this convex set

Tags: combinatorics, convex-optimization, discrete-geometry

Let $N \geq 2$ be an integer. Let $P:= \{ (a_1, \ldots, a_N) \in [0, 1]^N : \sum_n a_n = 2 \}$. Is $P$ the convex hull of $P \cap \{0, 1\}^N$?

Edit: This is apparently true, see the beginning of Section 2 [here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~billey/classes/root.systems/references/lam.postnikov.2005.pdf). Pointers to an explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: By [Krein–Milman theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krein%E2%80%93Milman_theorem), $P$ is the convex hull of its extreme points

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle: ok. The question is then -- are there any extreme points of $P$ besides the indicated ones?

Comment: yeah, this may be easier to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that $P = \{ a \in \mathbb{R}^N:  \sum_n a_n = 2 \text{ and } 0 \leq a_i \leq 1 \ \forall i\}$. Hence $P$ is described with one equality(equivalent to two inequalities basically) and $2N$ inequalities. A vertex (i.e. an extreme point) of $P \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is can be described as a feasible point (i.e. lying in $P$) such that $N$ of the aforementioned inequalities are satisfied with equality. Finding these should be fairly easy. Actually, the vertices should be the set of all points in $\{0,1\}^N$ with exactly two $1$'s. Therefore your initial statement is true.

Comment: "A vertex (i.e. an extreme point) of P is can be described as a feasible point (i.e. lying in P) such that [at least] N of the aforementioned inequalities are satisfied with equality." I agree that this is true here. Is this true for a general (nondegenerate) polytope in N dimensions?

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion: In general a $k$-dimensional face $F$ of a polytope $P$ is defined as the intersection of $P$ with a supporting hyperplane and if the affine hull of $F$ has dimension $k$. A vertex is then a $0$-dimensional face. Regarding your question: This is not true in general. At least not without requiring the inequalities to be 'irredundant'. E.g. see Schrijver 'theory of linear programming' p104: 'each vertex is determined by $n$ linearly independent equations form the systems Ax=b'.

Comment: Simple example: $P=\{ x=(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x_1 \leq 1, x_2 \leq 1, x_1 +x_2 \leq 2\}$. Then any point $(1,1,a)$ is feasible and satisfies $n+1$ inequalities with equatility ($n=3$ here of course). But $(1,1,a)$ is of course not a vertex ($P$ does not have any vertices). This is because the resulting system of equations is not linearly independent. In fact the equation $x_1 + x_2 \leq 2$ is redundant as it is already implied by the previous two.